# Orbeon Forms: Dynamic label not working in nested section

Tags: xpath, orbeon

I am using Orbeon Forms 2019.2.0.201912301747 CE.

My form structure looks like this:

```
<s-2>
 <s-2-iteration>
  <s-2-position>
   ...
   <s-2.7>
    <s-2.7-iteration>
     <s-2.7-position>
      ...
     </s-2.7-position>
    </s-2.7-iteration>
   </s-2.7>
   ...
  </s-2-position>
 </s-2-iteration>
</s-2>
```

Tags `<...-position>` are sections in which I would like to have dynamic labels like "Position no X", where X is the repeat number. I've done that for `<s-2-position>` tag using `xxf:repeat-position()` in Section Settings/Label/Template Parameters ([screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr77O.png)).

But, when I've tried to do that in `<s-2.7-position>` tag, which is nested in `<s-2-position>` it did not work. Label was blank when running form. Futhermore, when I've tried to use any sort of dynamic label in `<s-2.7-position>` and in any other tag inside `<s-2.7-position>` it did not work as well.

So, have you ever encountered this problem? What is the solution/workaround? Is that Orbeon Froms error?

Thank you!

Comment: I have found a cause of the problem. After renaming tag `<s-2.7-position>` into anything not starting with `s-2.7` dynamic labels with template parameters are working, including `xxf:repeat-position()`.

Comment: Or rather something not including `s-2.7`, even separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a cause of the problem. After renaming tag `<s-2.7-position>` into anything not including `s-2.7` (even separated) dynamic labels with template parameters are working, including `xxf:repeat-position()`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it would make sense for `xxf:repeat-position()` to work in this case, or to have higher level Form Runner specific functions. This is covered by the request for enhancement (RFE) [#4144](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4144). In the meantime, you can try, as mention in the RFE, something like:

```
count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

Comment: I also added a +1 from OP on [#4144](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4144). ‑Alex

Comment: Thaks for answer, but my problem was even more general. Any template parameter (even XPath Expression: `1`) was giving empty label in result. I found another cause of it and described it in comment to question. After fix even `xxf:repeat-position()` is working.

Comment: And I think above is a good candidate for an to-fix issue on your GitHub as well.

Comment: @KamilKoszarny I read your comments on the question, but don't quite understand what the situation is. I imagine that this is with a form you created in Form Builder? Does the problem also happen without doing any changes to the source of the form? If so, would it be possible for you to create a minimal example, and share the source code with us?

Comment: Sure, I've posted example in today's answer below. Form was created in Form Builder and can be reproduced without direct changes in source (only using GUI) as well.

Comment: @KamilKoszarny I see you posted the source of a form under "Not working form" in an answer (BTW, answers on Stack Overflow are supposed to be for answer, not for additional information.) I imported this as a form on https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/6fb69d9054577b13915ee295a2d759b024a35962. What should I do next to reproduce the problem, i.e. what are the steps? What is the behavior you observe? And what is the behavior you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I did not managed to fit the form here. If you change `s-foo` in this form into `s-2.7-pozycja` then label of this section is not showing (again sorry for confusing).  Expected behavior is to have label with "Position X" where X is repetition number.

Comment: In edited answer below I uploaded images with wrong and expected behavior. Also changed "Not working form" into "Working form" as posted form is with described fix (again sorry for confusing).

Answer (score 0):

After changing names of `s-2.7-pozycja` tags in below form into `s-foo`, labels of those tags show correctly. Before labels were not shown at all (empty).

**Working form:**

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         fr:data-format-version="4.0.0">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>PL825 - Projekt podziału przemieszczenia</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true" xxf:analysis.calculate="true"
                  xxf:hint.appearance="tooltip">

            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>
                    <s-2>
                        <s-2-iteration>
                            <s-2-pozycja>
                                <s-2.7>
                                    <s-2.7-iteration>
                                        <s-foo>
                                            <grid-7>
                                                <control-1/>
                                            </grid-7>
                                        </s-foo>
                                    </s-2.7-iteration>
                                </s-2.7>
                            </s-2-pozycja>
                        </s-2-iteration>
                    </s-2>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Bindings -->
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xf:bind id="s-2-bind" ref="s-2" name="s-2">
                    <xf:bind id="s-2-iteration-bind" ref="s-2-iteration" name="s-2-iteration">
                        <xf:bind id="s-2-pozycja-bind" ref="s-2-pozycja" name="s-2-pozycja">
                            <xf:bind id="s-2.7-bind" ref="s-2.7" name="s-2.7">
                                <xf:bind id="s-2.7-iteration-bind" ref="s-2.7-iteration" name="s-2.7-iteration">
                                    <xf:bind id="s-foo-bind" ref="s-foo" name="s-foo">
                                        <xf:bind id="grid-7-bind" ref="grid-7" name="grid-7">
                                            <xf:bind id="control-1-bind" ref="control-1" name="control-1" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                                        </xf:bind>
                                    </xf:bind>
                                </xf:bind>
                            </xf:bind>
                        </xf:bind>
                    </xf:bind>
                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>

            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>EMSC</application-name>
                    <form-name>PL825</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="pl">PL825 - Projekt podziału przemieszczenia</title>
                    <description xml:lang="pl"/>
                    <created-with-version>2019.2.0.201912301747 CE</created-with-version>
                    <updated-with-version>2019.2.0.201912301747 CE</updated-with-version>
                    <library-versions>
                        <orbeon>1</orbeon>
                    </library-versions>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Attachments -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments/>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- All form resources -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="pl">
                        <control-1>
                            <label/>
                            <hint/>
                        </control-1>
                        <s-2.7>
                            <label>2.7 </label>
                        </s-2.7>
                        <s-foo>
                            <label>Position {$nr_poz}</label>
                        </s-foo>
                        <s-2>
                            <label>2. </label>
                        </s-2>
                        <s-2-pozycja>
                            <label>Position {$nr_poz}</label>
                        </s-2-pozycja>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" id="s-2-template">
                <s-2-iteration>
                    <s-2-pozycja>
                        <s-2.7>
                            <s-2.7-iteration>
                                <s-foo>
                                    <grid-7>
                                        <control-1/>
                                    </grid-7>
                                </s-foo>
                            </s-2.7-iteration>
                        </s-2.7>
                    </s-2-pozycja>
                </s-2-iteration>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" id="s-2.7-template">
                <s-2.7-iteration>
                    <s-foo>
                        <grid-7>
                            <control-1/>
                        </grid-7>
                    </s-foo>
                </s-2.7-iteration>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
                <fr:section id="s-2-section" bind="s-2-bind" repeat="content" min="2"
                            template="instance('s-2-template')"
                            apply-defaults="true"
                            fb:initial-iterations="first">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/s-2/label"/>
                    <fr:section id="s-2-pozycja-section" bind="s-2-pozycja-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/s-2-pozycja/label">
                            <fr:param type="ExpressionParam">
                                <fr:name>nr_poz</fr:name>
                                <fr:expr>xxf:repeat-position()</fr:expr>
                            </fr:param>
                        </xf:label>
                        <fr:section id="s-2.7-section" bind="s-2.7-bind" repeat="content" max="99"
                                    template="instance('s-2.7-template')"
                                    apply-defaults="true"
                                    fb:initial-iterations="first">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/s-2.7/label"/>
                            <fr:section id="s-foo-section" bind="s-foo-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/s-foo/label">
                                    <fr:param type="ExpressionParam">
                                        <fr:name>nr_poz</fr:name>
                                        <fr:expr>xxf:repeat-position()</fr:expr>
                                    </fr:param>
                                </xf:label>
                                <fr:grid id="grid-7-grid" bind="grid-7-bind">
                                    <fr:c x="1" y="1" w="12">
                                        <xf:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
                                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                        </xf:input>
                                    </fr:c>
                                </fr:grid>
                            </fr:section>
                        </fr:section>
                    </fr:section>
                </fr:section>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>`
```

Wrong behavior

[image: Wrong behavior]

Expected behavior

[image: Expected behavior]